# Devices folder in Finder?

Tags: finder, filesystem

Is there anyway that I can view the `/dev` folder with its contained pseudo-files inside of Finder? I can access it just fine in the terminal with `cd /dev`, but in Finder it doesn't show up even with `AppleShowAllFiles` active.

Comment: What is the reasoning?  /dev doesn't contain actual files, it is just referencing devices connected to the machine.

Answer (score 1):

No, just had a fiddle and it appears there is no way to do that.

**Neither of these work:**

In terminal:

```
open .
```

will open the current directory in Finder.

Unhiding it with:

```
sudo chflags nohidden dirname
```

Does not work either. (Error --> chflags: dev/: Operation not supported)